# Select all cells with data

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data in an Excel Worksheet. I would like to select all the cells which contain data.

For example, for a worksheet with data in cells A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, and C3, how can I select just this 3x3 grid, and not the entire sheet?

I am looking for something like `ActiveSheet.SelectUsedCells`.

Comment: See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba and:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557916/excel-macro-select-all-cells-with-data-and-format-as-table

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

Or if you don't necessarily start at A1:

```
Range("C6").Select  ' Select a cell that you know you populated'
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

Answer (score 19):

You might also want to look at the `CurrentRegion` property.  This will select a contiguous range that is bounded by empty cells, so might be a more elegant way of doing this, depending on the format of your worksheet.

For example:

```
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
```