# How to Select All or (Ctrl + A) dynamic table doesn't matter how big it is

Tags: excel, vba

This is my sample data.

[image]

And this is the VBA code produced with macro.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:C3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$C$3"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
    Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9"
End Sub
```

How do I get the macro code?

1. Developer > Record Macro
2. Select all (ctrl + A) inside any cells within `A1:C3`
3. Home > Format as Table

Output

[image]

The problem is my data is dynamic and not necessarily stay at `A1:C3`.

It could be bigger or smaller.

E.g., let say I've bigger within range `A1:C4` in different Ms Excel file.

[image]

The code above won't select all, instead it selects only `A1:C3`.

[image]

Last row `A4:C4` won't be affected with this code.

How do I change this doesn't matter how big the table is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557916/excel-macro-select-all-cells-with-data-and-format-as-table

Answer (score 4):

#### Solution 1

You can use `Range("A1").CurrentRegion` to get the area of continous data (which is the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SelectCurrentRegion()
    Dim MyData As Range
    Set MyData = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    'don't use .select this is just for illustrating
    MyData.Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Note that the number in cell D6 is not vertically nor horizontally connected with the other data. Therefore it is not selected by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> or `.CurrentRegion`.

#### Solution 2

Or `Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange` to get the area of all data:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SelectCurrentRegion()
    Dim MyData As Range
    Set MyData = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    
    'don't use .select this is just for illustrating
    MyData.Select
End Sub
```

[image]

You might benefit from reading
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Thanks @Pᴇʜ.

I'm new to macro & VBA and have no idea how to implement your code in mine.

Could you please put a full code to produce the table as shown in the screenshot above?

Comment: ++ nicely explained

Comment: I copy paste the code and getting the following error:

`Run-time error '1004':

Select method of Range class failed
`

Comment: @user11392987 make sure you reference the correct worksheet (adjust the name in the code) and add your table like following using the definde `MyData` range: `Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, MyData, , xlYes).Name = "Table1"`

Answer (score 1):

@Pᴇʜ has already given you 2 solutions. Here is Solution 3. I would prefer finding last row and column over `UsedRange` and then construct the range. I have explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba/11169920#11169920) why I do not prefer using `UsedRange`

**Solution 3**

Find the last row and last column and then create your range

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    
    '~~> Change this to relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
        After:=.Range("A1"), _
        Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False).Row

        LastColumn = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
        After:=.Range("A1"), _
        Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False).Column
        
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
        
        Debug.Print rng.Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Siddharth Rout, I put this code on `Module1` and execute it but nothing happen

Comment: I think you are mistaken how this code works... @Pᴇʜ and my code tells you how to get your range and not create a table. You already have the code in your question to create the table. You need to combine both the codes to achieve what you want. I can give you the code in a platter but I would like you to try it first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel tables then you can use `DataBodyRange` or `Range` Properties to select what you need to select.

```
Dim lstObj As ListObject
For Each lstObj In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
    lstObj.DataBodyRange.Select ' Will select only data without headers
    lstObj.Range.Select ' Will select complete table
Next lstObj
```

Comment: I think his idea was (according to his code) to create an Excel table (ListObject) out of a normal worksheet's data.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Oh, got confused with OP's post. I will keep it for now and see what OP says about it.

Comment: Thanks @Pᴇʜ & shrivallabha.redij. I wanted to create an excel table (my question has been updated).

I'm new to macro & VBA and have no idea how to implement your code in mine.

Could you please put a full code to produce the table as shown in the screenshot above?